# How to pass %0 as a string literal to an executable in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to call ffmpeg in a batch file using the format for finding image files 'frame-%03d.bmp" (to get frame-000 to frame-999), and the batch file is replacing the %0 with the name of the batch file. I tried to escape the %0 by typing %%0 instead but it still produced the same issue.

I have tried googling for the last 30 mins and can't figure out how to phrase the issue to find any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you used `^` before the `%0`? `^` (caret) is a breakout key.

Comment: I did try that, as well as using %. But I just discovered 3 %'s before %0 fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, though I am not happy about it. You have to put '%%%' in front of it, to make the argument `frame-%%%%03d.bmp`.